# How can I get the autoincremented id when I insert a record in a table via jdbctemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

```
private void insertIntoMyTable (Myclass m) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NAME) VALUES (?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, m.getName());
}
```

When the above query inserts a record, the `ID` column in the table autoincrements.

Is there a way to get this auto incremented ID back at the time of the insertion. So in this example the return value of my method would be `int`

Comment: I think you may need a select just after the insert in a transaction.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check the [Chapter 11. Data access using JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys) reference. You can use `jdbcTemplate.update` as:

**EDIT**
Added imports as asked

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
```

following is the code usage:

```
final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into my_test (name) values(?)";
final String name = "Rob";
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"id"});
            ps.setString(1, name);
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);
// keyHolder.getKey() now contains the generated key
```

Comment: would you please put the imports?

Comment: We also now need to pass the Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS as another argument to prepareStatement

Comment: can someone write an addendum for multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I get id generated by database (MSSQL) after insert like below, imports:

```
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet;
  import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
```

and the code snippet:

```
    final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO [table]\n"
            + " ([column_1]\n"
            + " ,[column_2])\n"
            + " VALUES\n" +
            " (?, ?)";

    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_INVOICE_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "test 1");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "test 2");

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet keys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();

    if (keys.next()) {
        Integer generatedId = keys.getInt(1); //id returned after insert execution
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget the line with `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`!

Answer (score 1):

JdbcTemplate is at the core of Spring. Another option is to use [SimpleJdbcInsert](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html).

```
SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate);
simpleJdbcInsert
    .withTableName("TABLENAME")
    .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID");
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("COL1", model.getCol1())
    .addValue("COL2", model.getCol2());
Number number = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(params);
```

You can still @Autowire jdbcTemplate. To me, this is more convenient than working with jdbcTemplate.update() method and KeyHolder to get the actual id.

Example code snippet is tested with [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) and should work with the usual databases.

Use of [Spring JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) is another option - if ORM is for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
public class PersonDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<Person> index() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM person", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
    }

    public Person show(int id){
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id=?", new Object[]{id}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class))
                .stream().findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Person person){
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO person (name, age, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", person.getName(), person.getAge(), person.getEmail());
    }

    public void edit(Integer id, Person person) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE person SET name = ?, age = ?, email = ? WHERE id = ?", person.getName(), person.getAge(), person.getEmail(), id);
    }

    public void delete(Integer id) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?", id);
    }
}
```