# How to get the value from MyBatis?

Tags: java, oracle10g, mybatis

I'm having a problem in retrieving a property from myBatis. It says `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What I want is to get only the `user_id` from the result map which is auto generated after using a function to insert values to the database (I'm using oracle 10g).

My code in my mapper is as follows

```
<resultMap type="User" id="userMap">
    <result property="userId" column="user_id"/>
    <result property="someProperty1" column="property_1"/>
    <result property="someProperty2" column="property_2"/>
</resultMap>

<insert id="addUser" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { CALL 
    #{userResult, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap=userMap} :=
    PROJECT.create_user(
            #{surname,      javaType=String,    jdbcType=VARCHAR,   mode=IN},
            #{givenName,    javaType=String,    jdbcType=VARCHAR,   mode=IN},
            #{middleName,   javaType=String,    jdbcType=VARCHAR,   mode=IN}    
    )}
</insert>
```

Here is where the `java.lang.NullPointerException` occurs

```
return Integer.parseInt(paramMap.get("userId").toString());
```

I'm using `private Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();` It seems that I've used `paramMap.get("userId")` is wrong but I am not sure with this.

Any suggestions or hints would be very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe `paramMap` or `userId` is null, you can debug it see which one is null.

Comment: okay thanks @Reno!

Answer (score 1):

Getting auto-generated keys back from the database has never been standardized, so it tends to be database-specific. With Oracle, you need to first select the new key value from a sequence, do the insert and return the result. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026785/how-to-call-a-oracle-database-sequence-number-by-using-mybatis) has the real oil for a MyBatis project.

Some of the more recent Java ER mapping frameworks are handling this transparently. For instance Spring JDBC Template has a GeneratedKeyHolder object that abstracts the database work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882874/how-can-i-get-the-autoincremented-id-when-i-insert-a-record-in-a-table-via-jdbct) for an example.